# Json Schema validation without NewtonSoft or NJsonSchema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

There is a good way to schema validation without using the library from Newtonsoft? The new library is awesome but paid. And NJsonSchema uses the paid library from NewtonSoft. I would like to know if there is an out-of-the-box in C# or a good free alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend JsonSchema.Net from here:
[https://json-schema.org/implementations](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validators)

Answer (score 1):

You can stay with NJsonSchema, because it only uses [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), which is free but not [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema), which isn't free.